# What is the ":" operator for in HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

In HTML code i have seen **:** operator many times used by the designer. So anyone please help me out to let me  know that what is the use of **:** operator.

Here the code is

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<demo:title>Demo</demo:title> 
<demo:css />
<demo:head />
</head>
<body>
<demo:header />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

: is not valid in HTML.  It could theoretically be used for a namespace alias in XHTML, but there are no namespaces declared in your example. It's meaningless.